# Equals() vs Static string.Equals()

Tags: c#

Reading about string comparison in c# i found many ways to compare 2 strings to see if they are equal.

I was used to `==` coming from c++ but i learned that if you compare an object with a string then `==` defaults to reference value (or something like that).

Then for the `Equals()` method lets say i have 2 strings.

```
string s1 = null;
string s2 = "Hello";
```

if i do `s1.Equals(s2);`

I get an **null-reference exception** cause the first string is null

But if i do

`string.equals(s1,s2);`

It will simply return `false` if one of the values is `null` and if both the values are `null` it will return `true` since both strings would be equal in that they are both `null`.

So is there any reason not to always use the `string.equals()` method.
Also another thing is that if i type the `string.equals()` with a capital S in the string like this **S**`tring.equals()` then it wll still run the same as if i had it lower case but the IDE (visual studio 2015) will tell me that it can be simplified and when i simplify it it turn it to a lower case s. Why is that?

Comment: Your understanding of `==` is wrong for C#. `==` for strings is going to be the same as `string.Equals()`. That is not true for Java, which may be the source of your mixup.

Comment: For the question `string` vs `String`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: @glorin specify which `.Equals`! is going to be the same as the `static string.Equals(s1, s2)`

Comment: You are providing a very obvious reason why you *don't* want to use String.Equals().  It hides a nasty bug in your code.  Don't hide bugs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/why-would-you-use-string-equals-over, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: Glorin well i am speaking generally about comparisons string is just for example.

Comment: Hans what do you mean sorry i didn't understand.

Comment: Note that the `Equals(string)` exists because a `string` is `IEquatable<string>`, so to implement the interface. `Equals(object)` exists because it override the `object` method `Equals(object)`

Comment: `s1` is `null`... It isn't referenced to anything, so you cannot call `s1.Equals`

Comment: So what would be the recommended way to do comparisons in c# or does it have to do depending on the type compared?

Comment: `s1.Equals(s2)` throws an exception when `s1` is null because you can't call an instance method on a null reference.

Comment: @sab669 unless you actually need to do a comparison, there's a severe performance hit using `String.Compare` vs `String.Equals` if you are checking for equality (and not actually comparing). May not be important while doing trivial operations, but might be very important if you have the need to check hundreds of thousands of strings in a tight loop. Checking for equality is much faster than comparing.

Comment: @sab669 same thing actually, doing comparisons (other than byte-per-byte, which is what the non-overloaded `string.Equals` uses) that use the culture information are magnitudes of order less performant than byte equality (you can argue this, I haven't profiled, but the implementation of those is far more complicated and requires many lookups per character, so I'm quite positive it'll be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals(v=vs.110).aspx), the `string.Equals` method

> Determines whether two String objects have the same value.

This is why `string.equals(s1,s2);` would always return false in your case, and if both `s1` and `s2` are null or have the same value would return true.

> Also another thing is that if i type the string.equals() with a
>   capital S in the string like this String.equals() then it wll still
>   run the same as if i had it lower case but the IDE (visual studio
>   2015) will tell me that it can be simplified and when i simplify it it
>   turn it to a lower case s. Why is that?

The `string` is a C# primitive, while `System.String` or simple `String` is the corresponding FCL (Framework Class Library) type. It is the same like `int` and `Int32`, where `int` is a C# primitive and `Int32` is the corresponding FLC type.

Comment: This is why string.equals(s1,s2); would always return true in your case, and if both s1 and s2 are null or have the same value would return false.  You mean it would return true correct?

Comment: @GeorgeOscStephan correct :( Thank you very much :)

Comment: Actually, `string` [is not a primitive type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965752/is-string-a-primitive-type) in C#

Answer (score 3):

Both methods perform these steps:

1. Check if both strings share the same reference (and return `true` if they do). They do this by checking the object references (it does it by checking `(object)a==(object)b`: the `==` operator on two `object` variables only checks for reference). Note that this step also returns `true` if both objects are `null`.
2. Check if either is `null` (and return `false` if any of them are)
3. Check if both lengths match (and return `false` if they don't)
4. If it comes to this point, it checks the bytes of each and see if they match (unless you have specified a type of `StringComparison` in one of the overloads) (side note: the byte comparison is implemented quite well and performant even being managed unsafe code... but this is an implementation detail that you shouldn't care about)

Whether you use one or the another (if you are sure your instance is not `null`) is up to you. Both basically do the same and they are equally performant.

*Links to implementation: [instance Equals method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,526) and 
[static string.Equals](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,594)*

You can't call instance methods on `null` instances, which is why it's throwing a `NullReferenceException` for you... however the fact that your instance is `null` ***may*** be important (depending on your specifications), you may want to check for `null` before the comparison and act accordingly (using `string.Equals` would hide that away, and may be more bug-prone). If it isn't important to your specifications, then using one or the other is simply a design decision.

If you are interested, the operator `==` for two string types is implemented like ([source link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,661)):

```
public static bool operator == (String a, String b) {
   return String.Equals(a, b);
}
```

So doing `a == b` is the same as doing `string.Equals(a,b)`

As for `String` and `string`, the former is `System.String` (which requires to have a `using System;` on top, or to specify the whole `System.String.Equals`), and the latter is a built-in alias (which doesn't require `using System;` on top). You can use either, they act exactly the same