# Primitive / Non-Nullable typenames in C#

Tags: c#

What are the primitive typenames in C#? Yes, we have a similar answer, but that only mention types, not the typenames:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13530321/3691653

E.g. it mentions types such as `System.Int32` and `System.Single` but not typenames `int` and `float` which also compiles for me. So what is the full list of typenames including its aliases?

In other words, I am interested about non-nullable typenames / typenames that require the Nullable<> keyword in order to be able to be set as null.

Comment: First, that answer defines all the 'typenames' you may want, just read the third item in the list. Second, there is no such thing as 'typename'  specifically distinct from type — e.g., `System.Int32` is a _.NET type_, `int` is a C# alias for that type. They are essentially the same thing. Third, why not trying search the [C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) before asking?

Answer (score 1):

Like these:

```
alias   type (in System namespace)

byte    Byte
sbyte   SByte
short   Int16
ushort  UInt16
int     Int32
uint    UInt32
long    Int64
ulong   UInt64
decimal Decimal
float   Single
double  Double
```

Read the rest at  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types and typenames that require the `Nullable<>` are two totally separate things.

Anything that is declared a `struct` instead of as a `class` is non nullable and requires `Nullable<>` to be wrapped around it to be set null.

A "Complete List" is impossible because anyone can write their own structs.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is whether a given Type can be wrapped into a Nullable<> or not, then it's equivalent to asking whether it is a value type or not:

```
        Type someType = typeof(int); // then, try to change this to "typeof(string)"
        Type someTypeNullable = null;
        if (someType.IsValueType)
        {
            someTypeNullable = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(someType);
        }
        if (someTypeNullable != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nullable version: " + someType + "?");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(someType + " is a reference type");
        }
```