# Why I can't use string as field of IComponentData in Unity Entities?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to keep player name in IComponentData

```
public struct PlayerNameTag : IComponentData {
    public string playerName;
}
```

but I get the following error: ArgumentException: Components.UITags.Creation.PlayerPortraitTag contains a field of System.String, which is neither primitive nor blittable.

Where I must keep string datas?

Comment: Because strings are not [primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965758/1663383) nor [blittable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [NativeString](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.0/api/Unity.Entities.NativeString64.html) creates an unmanaged blittable string and is usable in IComponentData.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the memory size of each field cannot dynamically change. In a string, the size of the string changes whenever you set the string. Obviously, the string: "This has more characters" is larger in memory than the string: "less characters".

So, you'll need to make all the fields have a fixed memory. To do that with a string, use the `FixedString32Bytes` or `FixedString64Bytes` (and so on...) types.